# Android App Crashes at Execution

Tags: android, eclipse

please i tried coding an android app using eclipse luna. I am writing a client gcm codes to push notifications. I have finished without any compiling errors, but wen i execute it on the mobile phone, the app crashes. Please below is the log i have been getting. Thanks for helping

```
    05-23 23:07:27.303: D/AndroidRuntime(18211): Shutting down VM
    05-23 23:07:27.303: W/dalvikvm(18211): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41f522a0)
    05-23 23:07:27.303: E/AndroidRuntime(18211): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    05-23 23:07:27.303: E/AndroidRuntime(18211): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.prgguru.example/com.prgguru.example.MainActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.prgguru.example/com.prgguru.example.HomeActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?       05-23 23:07:27.303: E/AndroidRuntime(18211):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
    05-23 23:07:27.303: E/AndroidRuntime(18211):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
    05-23 23:07:27.303: E/AndroidRuntime(18211):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
    05-23 23:07:27.303: E/AndroidRuntime(18211):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
    05-23 23:07:27.303: E/AndroidRuntime(18211):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    05-23 23:07:27.303: E/AndroidRuntime(18211):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    05-23 23:07:27.303: E/AndroidRuntime(18211):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
    05-23 23:07:27.303: E/AndroidRuntime(18211):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    05-23 23:07:27.303: E/AndroidRuntime(18211):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    05-23 23:07:27.303: E/AndroidRuntime(18211):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
    05-23 23:07:27.303: E/AndroidRuntime(18211):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
    05-23 23:07:27.303: E/AndroidRuntime(18211):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    05-23 23:07:27.303: E/AndroidRuntime(18211): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activityclass {com.prgguru.example/com.prgguru.example.HomeActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
    05-23 23:07:27.303: E/AndroidRuntime(18211):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1556)
    05-23 23:07:27.303: E/AndroidRuntime(18211):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1431)
    05-23 23:07:27.303: E/AndroidRuntime(18211):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3428)
    05-23 23:07:27.303: E/AndroidRuntime(18211):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3389)
    05-23 23:07:27.303: E/AndroidRuntime(18211):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3599)
    05-23 23:07:27.303: E/AndroidRuntime(18211):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3567)
    05-23 23:07:27.303: E/AndroidRuntime(18211):    at com.prgguru.example.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:61)
    05-23 23:07:27.303: E/AndroidRuntime(18211):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5188)
    05-23 23:07:27.303: E/AndroidRuntime(18211):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
    05-23 23:07:27.303: E/AndroidRuntime(18211):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
    05-23 23:07:27.303: E/AndroidRuntime(18211):    ... 11 more
    05-23 23:07:27.343: D/dalvikvm(18211): GC_CONCURRENT freed 224K, 13% free 7212K/8199K, paused 12ms+2ms, total 35ms
```

below is also my manifest file. this is how i make the manifest file

```
    `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.prgguru.example"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <!-- GCM requires Android SDK version 2.2 (API level 8) or above. -->
        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

        <!-- GCM connects to Internet Services. -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

        <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

        <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

        <!-- Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages. -->
        <permission
            android:name="com.prgguru.example.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature" />

        <uses-permission android:name="com.prgguru.example.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

        <!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

        <!-- Network State Permissions to detect Internet status -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

        <!-- Permission to vibrate -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

        <!-- Main activity. -->
        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

             <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


            <!-- Register Activity -->
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>



            <receiver
                android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
                android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
                <intent-filter>

                    <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                    <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                    <category android:name="com.prgguru.example" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>

            <service android:name=".GCMNotificationIntentService" />
        </application>

    </manifest>`
```

Comment: Have you read the stack trace? Specifically this part? *Unable to find explicit activityclass {com.prgguru.example/com.prgguru.example.HomeActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?*

Comment: Please i have been able to resolved it. Thanks, I had register all my activities into the manifest file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you make a new Activity and are going to display it you need to add a reference to it in your AndroidManifest.xml

For example you can simply do

```
<activity name="your.package.activityname" />
```

For more information see, [Declaring class names](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#filec) in the documentation.